# Dnn 7.01.01 requiring profile settings not being enforced on first login of new user

Tags: security, dotnetnuke

I am trying to sort out a peculiar behavior when creating new users as a site Admin on our Dnn installation.

I have gone into the Admin > Site Settings > User Account Settings > Profile Settings and changed a few of the fields to Required (FirstName, LastName, Title, Address etc) with Required and Visible checked and Default Visibility set to 'AllUsers'.

I have a requirement of 'None' for the 'User Registration' type, meaning the site Admin must create all new users. I also have a requirement that the password for new users be created randomly, instead of being assigned by the site Admin.

When the user is created in this manner, an email is sent with instructions to choose the 'Reset Password' option (if first time user). This built in Dnn function asks for the new user name (supplied in the email) and then sends another email with a reset password link with a token.

We are doing this to remove any password knowledge from the site Admin.

The problem is that when new users finally set their password and gain access to the system they are not being forced to fill in the required profile settings the first time (when they choose their password). They are required to fill them out when they log in the second time (without going through the reset password process).

We would really like them to be forced to complete the Profile Settings the first time regardless of whether they are setting their password via the password reset token link.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a workaround?

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Sounds to me like a bug with the new password management features, I would submit it to the DNN Jira site (support.dnnsoftware.com) and see if they have a work around available

Comment: I have submitted it. I'll post results here.

Comment: DNN verifies this issue and let me know that a fix will be forthcoming in a future update/upgrade. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found here:

https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-4213

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes